# How to prove the asymptotic upper bound for $T(n) = 2T(\lfloor n/2\rfloor + 17) + n$ is $O(n \log n)$?

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation, induction, divide-and-conquer

I met the problem

> Show that the solution to $T(n) = 2T(\lfloor n/2\rfloor + 17) + n$ is $O(n \log n)$

while reading Introduction to Algorithm. It's a question about the substitution method for solving recurrences.

Should I just assume $T(n/2 + 17) \leq O((n/2 + 17) \log(n/2 + 17))$ and then prove $T(n) \leq O(n \log n)$? Is this inductive assumption enough to solve it?

Comment: Please check out our related [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions) and see whether you can answer yourself.

Comment: Did you try using this inductive assumption? Let us know if it works.